# Login not appearing in initial render of angular application, using Behaviour of rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ng-if, rxjs-observables

**app.comp.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {LoginAuthService} from '../app/services/login-auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Kaksha-UI';
  isLogin$: Observable<boolean>

  constructor(private authService: LoginAuthService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLogin$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    // let valueFromSession = sessionStorage.getItem("userLogin");
    // if(valueFromSession != undefined){
    //   this.isLogin = true;
    // }
    console.log(this.isLogin$);
  }


  

}
```

**app.comp.html**

```
<nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kaksha</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class='nav-item active' >
                <a class="nav-link" *ngIf='!isLogin$ | async'   [routerLink]='["/login"]'>Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
                <a class="nav-link" *ngIf='!isLogin$| async'  [routerLink]='["/register"]'>Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
                <a class="nav-link" *ngIf='isLogin$ | async'  [routerLink]='["/register"]'>Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- <h1 *ngIf='isLogin$ | async' >Hello World</h1> -->

<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable ,BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginAuthService {

  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:1050/login';

  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private router:Router) { }

  
  get isLoggedIn(){
    console.log('I am called');

    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  loginUser(userObj){
    if(userObj.username != "" && userObj.password != ""){
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      console.log(this.loggedIn);
    }
  }
}
```

In the initial render of code the login/register button present in navbar should be rendered which is not rendering. If the code is analyzed in the initial render it should display login and register button

Also when I am going to login component and calling the registerUser function, then logout is appearing in the navbar

Comment: I think you might just need to change `!isLogin$ | async` to `!(isLogin$ | async)`. does that work?

Comment: No, to make it work i removed the async pipe  and subscribe the observables in ts file. That is the only thing made it work

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple async pipes on the same observable in template is consired bad practice and could lead to unwanted effects. Please consider putting the list items in a ng-container.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isLogin$ | async; else unauthorized">
        <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/register"]'>Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
        
    <ng-template #unauthorized>
        <li class='nav-item active'>
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/login"]'>Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]='["/register"]'>Register</a>
        </li>
    </ng-template>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this